# Get width of child in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, width

Say I have a `Frame` in tkinter with a set width and height (placed using the `place` method), and I add a child `Frame` to that parent `Frame` (using the `pack` method). In that child `Frame`, I add an arbitrary amount of widgets, so that the child `Frame`'s width is dynamically set depending on its children.

My question is **how do I get the width of the child** `Frame` **if it's width is greater than its parent?**

I know there's a `winfo_width` method to get the width of a widget, but it only returns the width of the parent `Frame` if its width is greater than its parent. In other words, how do I get the actual width of a widget, not just the width of the part of the widget that is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width will never be bigger than the parent frame.

You can call `winfo_reqwidth` to get the *requested* width of the widget. I'm not sure if that will give you the answer you are looking for. I'm not entirely what the real problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wanted the width before it was clipped by the parent's size.